# Actualizar BD con backend django y formulario post via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

Teniendo en cuenta que tengo mi modelo `userPersonalizado`. Y este tiene 2 campos que quiero actualizar mediante un formulario, donde introducen un valor numérico y al hacerlo, se hace una operación matemática. Bueno el resultado de esa operación matemática lo quiero para actualizar los campos del usuario logeado, según el valor numérico introducido. Estoy importando la librería de `Jquery`.

Archivo `form.html`:

```
<div><form method="POST" class="form-data" action="{% url 'solit' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
  <h6>Tipo de peticion:{{form.petit}}</h6>
  <h6>Razon:{{form.razon}}</h6>
  <h6>{{form.solicitudes_id}}</h6>
  <h6>Fecha inicio:{{form.periodo_init}}</h6>
  <h6>Fecha fin:{{form.periodo_fin}}</h6>
  <h6>Introduzca dias a tomar<input id="dias" type="number" name="dias_adicion"></h6>
  <h6>Introduzca horas a tomar<input id="horas" type="number" name="horas_adicion"></h6>
  <input type="hidden" id="const_dias" name="d_pendientes" value="{{ user.d_pendientes }}">
  <input type="hidden" id="const_horas" name="h_pendientes" value="{{ user.h_pendientes }}">
Recuerde, que usted dispone de {{ user.d_pendientes }} dias y 
{{ user.h_pendientes }} horas a compensar <br>

<button type="submit" onclick="calculo()" class="boton">Guardar</button>
```

Estoy accediendo a 2 campos del modelo `userPersonalizado`, los cuales, quiero actualizar mediante una operación aritmetica, en este caso resta (-). Que lo logro mediante `js`

Archivo `javascript`:

```
function calculo()

{

   var dias = parseInt(document.getElementById('dias').value);
   var horas = parseFloat(document.getElementById('horas').value);
   var dias_base  = parseInt(document.getElementById('const_dias').value);
   var horas_base  = parseFloat(document.getElementById('const_horas').value);

   dias_base -= dias;
   horas_base -= horas;

alert(dias_base);
alert(horas_base);
} console.log(calculo);
```

Código `ajax`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var productForm = $(".form-data")

productForm.submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var thisForm = $(this)
  var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("action");
  var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
  var formData = thisForm.serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url: actionEndpoint,
    method: httpMethod,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data){
      console.log("success")
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(erroData){
      console.log("error")
      console.log(erroData)
    }
  })

 })
})
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
def solit(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    form = addiForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return JsonResponse({form:'form'})

form = addiForm()
return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', {'form':form})
```

Que es lo que tengo mal?, El error, que me aparece es `Internal server error 500`, en la consola de inspección `js`.

Y en la consola de `Django`, me muestra el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not addiForm [22/Jul/2019 12:20:51] "POST /solit/ HTTP/1.1" 500 14404
```

Comment: JsonResponse({form:'form'}) aqui le estas pasando una instancia de tu form no un json, es por eso que te da el error

Comment: @oegpyg, gracias por tu respuesta, entonces en el código como paso el json, como tu lo dices? gracias de antemano

Comment: depende de quieras retornar en tu respuesta

Comment: https://github.com/WiserTogether/django-remote-forms puedes usar esta libreria que te permite serializar forms y widgets

Comment: @oegpyg, Si retornar mi respuesta json, es guardar el valor resultante de la operación hecha en el fronted, entonces, como se haría en esa función de mi archivo views.py?? Gracias por la libreria, pero creo que me es mas facil, como lo estoy haciendo, por que asi con ese repo, no entiendo casi nada, igual gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: pero que es lo que quieres retornar, un resultado, un estatus de operacion?

Comment: Quiero que el resultado de la operación, se guarde en los campos del modelo en este caso serias: "horas_base" y "dias_base" correspondientes del user logeado.

Comment: Si y una vez guardado que queres que te responda el servidor? un estado por ejemplo {"status" : "OK", "msg": "se guardo con exito"}

Comment: si! seria perfecto, siempre y cuando guarde el resultado de la operación de js, que tengo arriba en el archivo javascript

Answer (score 1):

Segun lo comentado seria algo asi lo que precisas

```
def solit(request):
   if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
       form = addiForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return JsonResponse({'status': 'true', 'msg': 'Procesado Correctamente'})
       else:
           return JsonResponse({'status': 'false', 'msg': 'Los datos no son validos'})

   form = addiForm()
   return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', {'form':form})
```

Por lo que tu javascript quedaria asi:

```
success: function(data){
      if (data.status){
          console.log(data.msg);
      }else{
          //aqui ocurrio un error al grabar
          console.log(data.msg);
      }
    },
```

Comment: que tal si creas un dict con status y msg y lo cambias solo si es "success", asi solo hay un solo return

Comment: Asi mismo es en optimizacion de codigo, solo que quiero que sea bien claro para el amigo

Comment: Bueno man, no se actualizo el valor del campo, pero si me muestra esto: "Procesado Correctamente", en el console de javascript. disuclpa las molestias @oegpyg

Comment: Puedes retornar el error de esta form en el msg form.errors

Comment: Tocando mas el archivo en la consola, de javacript, me manda esto: {status: "true", msg: "Procesado Correctamente"}
msg: "Procesado Correctamente"
status: "true", Pero aun asi no me guarda el valor resultante de la operación que tengo en mi pregunta junto al archivo javascript, algo estoy haciendo mal?